# Couldn't get approval for google ad's

Tags: angular, adsense

I developed and launched a website in Angular 4. As part of the integration with Google ads, I added the necessary google ad tags in my index.html page. I sent it for review to Google. But they rejected it saying "Valuable Inventory: No content". When I tried to investigate the issue, I came to know that the google checks for content in between the body tags in HTML page. So When I go to my website and right click and clicked 'view page source', I couldn't see any content except "app-root". As we know that Angular will embed all the content in "app-root" tag. How to overcome this problem and make the source page to show all the content. I request you to share some insights on this and how to proceed further. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

With Angular, all content is rendered by the javascript when the page loads; as the google crawler just parses the (empty) index.html, it will not find any content.

To make your page parsable by search engines and enable search engine optimization (SEO) you would have to render the content ahead of time.

Angular Universal offers such functionality by rendering the content on the server.
https://angular.io/guide/universal